# How do you make all Django Admin fields with ForeignKey dropdown selections whose count is over 50 - Be ReadOnly fields?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-admin

Example - If I have a FK field `created_by` to User model which has count of over 10000 User records. I want to check the count dynamically and set those dropdown fields as ReadOnly fields in Django Admin

Comment: Have you looked it up in the documentation? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields

Comment: Thanks that helped!